# config get request inside blade string is passing not value

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

config get request inside blade string is passing not value

```html
<tr>
<td>Please <a href="{{url(" . Config::get(custom.url) . ")}}" . "password/{{$token}}">Click here </a>to reset your password:</td>
</tr>
```

It's passing this

```
http://localhost:9000/%20.%20Config::get(custom.frontendUrl)%20.
```

this is not correct url. Please guide thanks

Comment: Not relevant to the issue, but is it `custom.url` or `custom.frontendUrl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Follow the below code.

```
<tr>
   <td>Please <a href="{{url(Config::get('custom.url'))}}password/{{$token}}">Click here </a>to reset your password:</td>
</tr>
```

I am assuming you have custom.php inside config

```
return array(
    'url' => 'localhost:9000/'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotation marks from your url, because your url is currently reading your config as a string:

```
<tr>
   <td>Please <a href="{{url(Config::get(custom.url))}}" . "password/{{$token}}">Click here </a>to reset your password:</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Use of undefined constant custom - assumed 'custom'

Comment: Try to clear your cache, and try again. And see more detailed log inside your `storage/logs` , maybe you can see why it fails there